# Finding prime numbers 1-100 and write them to file.

Tags: c++

Can someone help me figure out how to find all the prime numbers between 1-100 and        write them to a file?

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<fstream>            
 using namespace std;
 bool isPrime(int);
 int main()
 {
int iNum;
cout << "This program will calculate and store all the prime numbers between 1 and     

   100 "<<endl;
ofstream myfile( "writeto.txt" );

    for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
    isPrime(i);
    while(isPrime(i) == true)
        {
        myfile <<  i <<endl;
        break;

    }
    myfile.close();
return 0;
    }
 }

 bool isPrime(int iNum)
 {
 bool status;  
 if( iNum <= 1 )

 return false; 

  for( int i = 2; i < iNum; i++ ) 
 { 
     if( iNum % i == 0 ) 
         return false; 
  } 

 return true;

 }
```

How can I get this to work?
I have been working on this for a while and think it has to do something with my return. I am really lost and hope someone can help me. I am not looking for answers I just want someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Exact issue you are having pls

Comment: You dont need to call `isPrime` twice or do `==true` but neither is a bug.

Comment: The formatting is beyond bad...

Comment: Actually, looking at the code - there are so many bugs and just strange things that you really need to sit down and go through it step by step. It is not a code review service here. 1. Format your code in an easily readable way. 2. Learn to DEBUG!

Comment: Also, for the sake of sanity, only go to sqrt(i) to test for primes... thats just one approach to make it go faster, but it surely is the one which everyone should be capable of understanding why...

Comment: Thanks guys... Sorry I am a newbie to C++ and to this website. All the help is greatly appreciated. I will do my best to get the hang of how you guys do things on here.

Answer (score 6):

Your braces seem to be misplaced

```
        break;

    }
    myfile.close();
return 0;
    }
 }
```

should be

```
        break;

      }

    }
    myfile.close();
return 0;
 }
```

p.s. and `if` instead of `while` as ThinTim found, and the other issues he mentions. But in light of the `break` statement, this is the one causing the prime (pun intended) issue.

Your set of braces causes your program to exit after 1 number, if it isnt prime, and hang, if it is.

Answer (score 3):

Your `while` should be an `if`.

You don't need that `break` statement.

The first call to `isPrime` inside the loop does nothing.

You should be converting your numbers to characters when you write them.

As Karthik mentioned, your brackets are not closed correctly.

You should do a lot more review before you post questions to StackOverflow.

Comment: To be fair, it was one of the problems. I'm editing this answer as I find things. I've made a lot of edits...

Comment: ah, the code is making more sense taking your first two lines together.. He was emulating an `if` !!

Comment: Thanks guys... Sorry I am a newbie to C++ and to this website. All the help is greatly appreciated. I will do my best to get the hang of how you guys do things on here.

Comment: We were all new at some point. Try to focus on getting your program logically correct before writing it in code. Write out the steps on paper first (in english / pseudo-code), then translate it to C++ when you've proofread it, and you're confident that it's accurate.

Comment: Will do.  I have done everything that you guys suggested. Now I can get it to compile and it saves numbers to the file but the numbers look like garbage. This is what is saving to my file. 2357111317192329313741434753596167717379838997

Comment: [http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/1000.txt](http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/1000.txt), and [http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/01/the-great-newline-schism.html](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/01/the-great-newline-schism.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it. I cannot express how much i appreciate the help. You were much more helpful than my professor.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark one of the responses to your question as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    isPrime(i);
    while(isPrime(i) == true)
    {
        myfile <<  i <<endl;
        break;

    }
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The return 0; will make you quit the program after the first prime...

Correct would be

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    if(isPrime(i)) {
        myfile <<  i <<endl;
    }
}
myfile.close();
return 0;
```

Comment: Thanks guys... Sorry I am a newbie to C++ and to this website. All the help is greatly appreciated. I will do my best to get the hang of how you guys do things on here.

Comment: Now I can get it to compile and it saves numbers to the file but the numbers look like garbage.  This is what is saving to my file. 2357111317192329313741434753596167717379838997

Comment: I have tested your code, and it works fine for me. Looks like you are missing the << endl; in your code (since the row you have there is 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 etc...), so only the new line in between is missing

Comment: http://pastebin.com/whNxGzcT is the code I tested with. Note: your code would be fastest if you stored the list of primenumbers and did the modulo test only with prime numbers < sqrt(i)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it.   I cannot express how much i appreciate the help. You were much more helpful than my professor.